# Sum of two truncated normaly distributed variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two variables which are truncated normally distributed above zero (that is $X$ and $Y$ have the lower truncation point zero, their values are bounded above zero). Is $X+Y$ truncated normally distributed as well?

I read all the other questions and answers regarding the sum of truncated normally distributed variables and it seems to me like the sum is not truncated normally distriubted (even if $X$ and $Y$ have the same support). Is this correct?

More importantly, what is the intutions behind? Intuitively, I would actually expect that the sum of $X$ and $Y$ is truncated normally distributed as well. Which problem do I overlook?

Thank you.

Comment: I would say 
   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831714/sum-of-two-truncated-gaussian

Answer (score 0):

In an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/428781/15941), I showed that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent zero-mean
normal random
variables with the same variance $\sigma^2$, then, with $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$ being random variables whose joint density is 
$4f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathbf 1_{\{x>0, y> 0\}}$,
$$F_{\hat{X}+\hat{Y}}(\alpha) = P\{\hat{X}+\hat{Y} \leq \alpha\} = \left[\Phi\left(\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)
- \Phi\left(\frac{-\alpha}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)\right]^2
= \left[2\Phi\left(\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)
- 1\right]^2.$$
Can you work out from this whether the sum $\hat{X}+\hat{Y}$ has a
truncated normal distribution or not?

As to where your intuition is going wrong, consider whether what
your intuition is telling you is the same as insisting that for
*arbitrary* real numbers $x$ and $y$,
$ |x| + |y|$ always equals $|x+y|$. The claim is true if $x$ and
$y$ are positive numbers ....